# JpaRepository: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-data-jpa

I use spring-data-jpa. Without Spring Boot.

```
package ru.spb.repository;

public interface CrudUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

repository.

```
 package ru.spb.repository;

@Repository
public class UserRepository {

  @Autowired
  private CrudUserRepository crudRepository;
}
```

xml-config-files:

spring-app.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.spb.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.spb.repository"/
```

spring-db.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.spb.repository" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="ru.spb.repository"/>
```

in pom

```
<spring-data-jpa.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I catch the:

```
 NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.spb.repository.user.CrudUserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

Comment: By any chance you got duplicate `CrudUserRepository` class ? The exception trace shows package as `ru.spb.repository.*user*.CrudUserRepository` and the code shared is different . May be an incorrect import ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.
I add "classpath:spring/spring-db.xml" in param-values of contextConfigLocation in my web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring/spring-app.xml
        classpath:spring/spring-db.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
```